# nload Broken on Ubuntu 18

Tags: networking

nload displays network activity with ascii graphics but on ubuntu 18.04 these graphics are all scrambled while on ubuntu 16 it's OK.
Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 16 & Ubuntu Core 18 are intended for use without displays (ie. headless), Ubuntu 18.04 will be for a server or desktop so will have ascii text characters only (server) or graphics (desktop). There is no Ubuntu 18, server & desktop releases use a *year.month* standard; only specialist releases use *year* format such as Ubuntu Core 18 intended for IoT appliances/devices.  Be specific with versions/releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: In what way are these scrambled?

Comment: Well the HUD graphics are suppose to stay fixed on the screen but everything on the HUD scrolls to the left along with the network speed (the only thing that should scroll).

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is changing term

```
export TERM=xterm-color
```

Source: https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/813

**However this isn't permanent. I have to constantly run this command, even though i never reboot the server. A permanent solution is welcomed.**